# BLE BluetoothGattDescriptor setValue issue

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy

I have a very strange behavior when I'm trying to setValue() for Descriptor.

I'm trying to set an int value.

```
private void setDescriptor(int id) {
      BluetoothGattDescriptor descriptor = characteristic.getDescriptors().get(0);
            descriptor.setValue(BluetoothGattDescriptor.ENABLE_NOTIFICATION_VALUE);
            byte[] data = new byte[1];
            data[0] = (byte) (id);
            descriptor.setValue(data);
            mBluetoothGatt.writeDescriptor(descriptor);
}
```

If the id = 8 the `onCharacteristicChanged()` is never called.

If the id = 9 everything is Ok.

I can't think of a rational explanation for that behavior.

Answer (score 2):

I think it can be explained if you have a look at the binary representation of `8` and `9`:

- 8 = 0000 1000b
- 9 = 0000 1001b

To enable notifications you set the value `0000 0001b` as 1st byte and `0000 0000b` as 2nd byte.

On your BLE peripheral the implementation might look like this one:

```
void isNotificationRequested(byte value) : boolean {
     return value & 0x01 > 0
}
```

This is true, if you pass in `9`, but wrong for `8`.

This might be a logical reason for your observation, but I am not sure as I don't know the peripheral implementation.

Neverless, if you want to enable BLE notifications just use the constants defined in `BluetoothGattDescriptor` class:

```
private void setDescriptor() {
   BluetoothGattDescriptor descriptor = characteristic.getDescriptors().get(0);
   descriptor.setValue(BluetoothGattDescriptor.ENABLE_NOTIFICATION_VALUE);       
   mBluetoothGatt.writeDescriptor(descriptor);
}
```

I am not sure what's the purpose of the `id` variable? Your question is not providing any further information.